# How to sort data in Linux by Bash scripting from last to first

Tags: bash, sorting, console

How can I sort data in a text file on Linux by a command in the console from last to first?

I have got:

```
1:a k2:b k3:c k
```

And I need:

```
k k3:c k2:b 1:a
```

Comment: What is the sorting algorithm?

Comment: what is the format of the input? is that the contents of a file? a variable? an array? are you really sorting or just reversing the entries? what (code) have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sample input is in a variable:

```
$ x='1:a k2:b k3:c k'
```

One idea to reverse the direction of the space-delimited values:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${x}" | tac | tr '\n' ' '
k k3:c k2:b 1:a
```

Another idea using a `bash/for` loop:

```
$ unset pfx y
$ for i in ${x}            # do not wrap ${x} in double quotes since we DO want word splitting to occur
do
    y="${i}${pfx}${y}"
    pfx=" " 
done
$ echo "${y}"
k k3:c k2:b 1:a
```

Another idea using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--){printf "%s%s",pfx,$i;pfx=" "};printf "\n"}' <<< "$x"
k k3:c k2:b 1:a
```

Comment: Ok thank you but what should i change when string is "1:a\k2:b\k3:c\k"? How can i change "space" to "\"? I am talking about first answer "$ tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${x}" | tac | tr '\n' ' '"

Comment: @szytynamiare in the `tr` commands you would replace `' '` with `'\\'`; if you still have problems getting the code to work with your (real) data then consider asking a new question and provide the actual data you're working with